# Problem using .pack() and .place() in tkinter python

Tags: python, tkinter, pack

I want to create a scrollable frame and add some widgets but I have a problem, when I use entry.place() it doesn't show any entry but if I use pack() it works perfectly, any solution?

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

root = Tk() 
root.title("Entry Widgets") 

mainframe = Frame(root) 
mainframe.pack(fill = "both", expand = True) 

canvas = Canvas(mainframe) 
canvas.pack(side = "left", fill = "both", expand = True) 

scrollbar = Scrollbar(mainframe, orient = "vertical", command = canvas.yview) 
scrollbar.pack(side = "right", fill = "y") 

canvas.configure(yscrollcommand = scrollbar.set) 

frame = Frame(canvas) 
frame.pack(fill = "both", expand = True)
y=0
for i in range(50):
    entry = Entry(frame)
    entry.place(x=0,y=y)
    y = entry.winfo_y() + entry.winfo_height() + 5

canvas.create_window((0, 0), window = frame, anchor = 'nw')

frame.update_idletasks()

canvas.configure(scrollregion = canvas.bbox("all"))

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: `.place()` will not adjust the size of the parent frame, so the parent frame will be of size 1x1.

Answer (score 0):

Edited:

> I want to create a scrollable frame and add some widgets but I have a
> problem, when I use entry.place() it doesn't show any entry.

You cannot used `pack()` and `place()` when doing looping for `Entry` widget.

Just use `grid()` for second `frame`.

In case, you want to use `ttk` module.

Code:

```
from tkinter import *
from tkinter import ttk

root = Tk() 
root.title("Entry Widgets") 

mainframe = ttk.Frame(root) 
mainframe.pack(fill = "both", expand = True) 

canvas = Canvas(mainframe) 
canvas.pack(side = "left", fill = "both", expand = True) 

scrollbar = ttk.Scrollbar(canvas, orient = "vertical", command = canvas.yview) 
scrollbar.pack(side = "right", fill = "y") 

canvas.configure(yscrollcommand = scrollbar.set) 

frame = ttk.Frame(root) 
frame.pack(fill = "both", expand = True)

  
for i in range(50):
    entry = Entry(frame, width=50)
    entry.grid(column=0,row=i+10)
    

canvas.create_window((0, 0), window = frame, anchor = 'nw')

frame.update_idletasks()

canvas.configure(scrollregion = canvas.bbox("all"))

root.mainloop()
```

Screenshot:

[image]